# Textarea submit with enter

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form. When you hit the enter button. The form is going submit. But now i have a problem. When i hit the enter button in the textarea. Then the form is going submit. But in a textarea, a enter must be a enter.

How can i fix this? This is my code:

```
form.keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == enter) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('[type=submit]').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean form should not submit when focus is in textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();              
    $(this).find('[type=submit]').click();
    $("form").submit();       
})
```

Comment: I can not type in my fields .. .. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("input:submit").live('click',function(){         
     $("form").submit();
})
```