# Add enter for submit textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi i was created a new chat box,everithing is working but i need to when i click enter to sumit a message(to go to function Kucaj() ).Can you help me with that?
I add some code for enter but didnt work.Thanks

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
?>
<form name="forma2" action="login.php" method="post">
<table>
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name"submit" value"Login"/td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><a href="register.php">Registruj se!</a></td>
</tr>


<?php
exit;
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Maturski rad</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script>

function Klikni(){
        if(forma1.msg.value == ''){
                alert('Upisi poruku!');
                return;
            }
            var msg = forma1.msg.value;
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){
                            document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
 forma1.msg.value='';
                }
            xmlhttp.open('GET','insert.php?&msg='+msg,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        setInterval(function() {$('#chatlogs').load('logs.php');}, 2000);
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="forma1" action="#" id="forma1">

Username: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b></br>
Poruka: <br />
<textarea name="msg" style="width:500px; height:100px"></textarea><br />

<a href="#" onclick="Klikni()"; class="button">Posalji</a><br /><br />
<a href="logout.php" class="button">Izloguj se</a><br /><br />
<script>
$("forma1").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.Klikni();

    }}
    </script>
<div id="chatlogs">
Molim sacekajte da se ocita!!!
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `event.Klikni();`? Sure that shouldn't just be `Klikni();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `onsubmit=return Klikni();` attribute to your form and `return false;` to `Klikni` function  without using `.keypress()`. Form submitted on user pressing enter is a default behaviour.

```js
function Klikni(e) {
  alert("Enter pressed");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="forma1" action="#" id="forma1" onsubmit="return Klikni();">
  Put your cursor into the field and press Enter.<br>
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: I need help for my form1,thanks this work for my form2 ,but no in form1.Thanks

Comment: @Kiriyaga It works for any form. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try like this  [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364151/textarea-submit-with-enter?rq=1),

```
form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();              
    $(this).find('[type=submit]').click();
    $("form").submit();       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keydown instead of keypress as:

```
$("forma1").keydown(function(event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this.It should be like this `Klikni();` not like `event.Klikni();`

```
<script>
$("forma1").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        Klikni(); //no need of event there..    
    }}
    </script>
```